# Where does a linked server join perform computation?

Tags: sql-server, join

Let's say I have two SQL Server databases running on separate machines, call them `MachineA` and `MachineB`.

If I performed a query like the following

```
SELECT
    [Store].[Name] AS [Store Name],
    [Employee].[Name] AS [Employee Name],
    SUM([Sale].[Amount]) AS [Total Sales]
FROM [MachineA].[DatabaseA].[dbo].[Sales] AS [Sale]
INNER JOIN [MachineB].[DatabaseB].[dbo].[Employees] AS [Employee]
ON [Sale].[EmployeeId] = [Employee].[EmployeeId]
INNER JOIN [MachineB].[DatabaseB].[dbo].[Stores] AS [Store]
ON [Employee].[StoreId] = [Store].[StoreId]
GROUP BY [Store].[Name], [Employee].[Name]
```

Where we assume that the query is running on `MachineA`, where is work actually being performed? Does `MachineA` perform all the reads and send the rows over to `MachineB` for `JOIN`ing? Or is something more complicated going on here?

Comment: Check the execution plan and see the profiler urself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query optimizer will choose the best plan according to the linked server driver capabilities.